# How to filter a google sheet or excel table where only those rows are included where at least one of the cells is not blank

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Consider this table:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | s |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | s |

What's the filter formula (or any other formula for that matter) so that it will only retain the rows if any of the cells from col2 to col4 is not empty?

So the output should be:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | s |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | s |

Google sheet sample here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ugIbzetQGb0IV32iE0aG49wEK1xSuFLHqDUnzoLnGnM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: This worked: "=FILTER(A3:D5, (B3:B5 <> "") + (C3:C5 <> "") + (D3:D5 <> "")>0)" but there must be a simpler more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for Google Sheets:

```
=FILTER(A1:D4,BYROW(B1:D4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(x,"?*"))))
```

For ms365:

```
=FILTER(IF(A1:D4="","",A1:D4),BYROW(B1:D4,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x<>"")))))
```